# Local classes with Lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, method-reference, local-class

As I tested, the below code executes without any issues. But I could not understand the logic. Can someone please explain?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> london = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Chinatown","Croydon","Eden Park"));
    class City{
        private String name;
        City(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void printCity(){
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    london.stream().map(City::new).forEach(City::printCity); //Chinatown,Croydon,Eden Park
}
```

In the above example code, I have following questions.

1. The foreach method always takes a consumer object. In here printCity method is not a method that takes an argument. Still it works. How?
2. printCity method is not a static method here. How a City itself can call a instance method?

Comment: Consumer takes the object, which is passed via the method reference. It could also be expanded to `c -> c.printCity()`

Comment: It’s funny that you asked two questions, which answer each other…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consumer is equivalent to something like `c -> c.printCity()`, `(City c) -> c.printCity()`, or some long anonymous class that is a massive pain to type out.

The city instances are the subject of invocation. There is just syntactical sugar in the form of `City::printCity` which passes the method to the expression, where the instance is called.

Answer (score 5):

In your last statement you have currently used method references. This can be alternatively written as following:

```
london.stream().map(name -> new City(name)).forEach(city -> city.printCity());
```

As you can see above, the `map` returns `City` instances. So `forEach` gets `City` instances and calls `printCity` on each instance.

When using method references, `City::printCity` is not the same as calling `City.printCity`. See [Method References documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

> Method references are just easy-to-read lambda expressions.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation